# Задание: корни с чередующимиеся гласными

Tags: грамматика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дано задание (см.фото). Кто- н сможет объяснить суть задания? Надо добавить слово с чередующимися гласными. Но какое именно? 
Излагать материал - изложить (материал). Может, так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Излагать материал - изложить (материал).
```

Изложить - верно, но всё сочетание не переписывать, составить своё, например, изложить свою точку зрения.

Касаться злободневной темы - коснуться вопроса о работе и .д.

Comment: @ Людмила, спасибо. Все понятно теперь.